# Where to place array creation method in an MPI program

Tags: c++, concurrency, mpi, openmpi

I heard that all code in an MPI program should be decared between `MPI_Init` and `MPI_Finalize`. So what is the impact of the following difference in the beow MPI programs.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    int** array = createArray(START_VAL, ARRAY_SIZE);

    printArray(array, ARRAY_SIZE);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

And...

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int** array = createArray(START_VAL, ARRAY_SIZE);

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    printArray(array, ARRAY_SIZE);

    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either one is fine. The only thing mandated by the MPI Standard is that you can't use any other MPI functions before you call `MPI_INIT` or after you call `MPI_FINALIZE`. You can do other things before and after those calls, but you can't use MPI.

There's an entire section about this in the [MPI Standard](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-3.0/mpi30-report.pdf) (Section 8.7, older HTML version available [here](http://mpi-forum.org/docs/mpi-2.2/mpi22-report/node195.htm#Node195)).